# Save result of nested for loop in array in R

Tags: arrays, r, nested-loops

I have two variables that I would like to loop, for which I use a nested for loop in R. In the inner loop, I would like to loop over a certain time period and count every time some condition occurs (based on some other condition). Once one full iteration of this is finished, I would like to change one begin condition, for which I use the outer loop, and then repeat the process. The following code enables me to get almost everything I need, except that I get an array that stores the same value three times, instead of three separate values. The value is stores is the sum of the individual values I need. What line(s) of code am I missing?

```
for (j in 1:length(B)) {
  b[1] <- B[j];
  for (i in 2:Time) {
    b[i] <- b[i-1] + A - C;
    if (b[i] > b[1]) {
      D <- D + 1;
    } else if (b[i] <0) {
      E <- E + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Thus, I would like to store D and E for every outer iteration.

Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: is `if (b[1] > b[1])` on purpose?

Comment: change `b[1]>b[1]` condition after which before the very final `}` you will need to have `f=c(f,D)` which will store the `D` and also have `g=c(g,E)` which will store `E`. Ensure to declare `f` and `g` before the loop. On the very beginning

Comment: Solved! By including D[j] <- D[j] + 1 & E[j] <- E[j] + 1 the problem is solved